# glBufferStorage + glGetBufferSubData for retrieving data

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a `compute shader` that contains algorithms.

- Both the **CPU** and **GPU** jointly solve the tasks in an alternating fashion (cpu -> gpu -> cpu -> gpu).
- In each draw call I need to download data several times from the **GPU**.
- The communication is done via `shader storage buffers`.

Before I tried

- `glBufferData` + `glMapBufferRange(..., GL_MAP_READ_BIT)`

However, I only achieved **32 ms/frame** where a lot of the total time is spend in communication.

Now I tried

- `glBufferStorage` + `glGetBufferSubData`

It still achieves only **32 ms/frame**.

---

Am I doing something wrong? If I turn of the communication and calculate with *dummy values* then the performance jumps to **18 ms/frame**. Any idea how I can improve the timing?

Comment: If cpu or gpu is waiting idle when other is computing, then you should pipeline joint solvers so they are overlapped, the lesser latency one would be hidden.

Comment: it's a real-time application...

Comment: if glMapBufferRange is using dma, shouldn't it let you do the opposite way communication at the same time ? (if pci-e supports and gpu supports)

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan: Define "real-time". Do you mean "real-time like a game" or "real-time like a pacemaker, where someone dies if you drop a frame"?

Comment: I mean "realtime like a game". there is an input stream of camera frames. the algorithm returns only quality results if the view point changes just a little from frame to frame (optical flow). the stability is strongly coupled with FPS. I would like to remain around 60-30 fps.

Comment: So you're doing temporal stuff? Temporal AA, temporal SSAO or something like that?

Comment: @thokra It is actually some image processing where intermediate results are ping-ponged multiple times between **gpu** and **cpu** in each frame.

Comment: Can't you bounce back the compute shader results indirectly, i.e. enqueue the next processing step indirectly via `gl[Multi]Draw{Arrays|Elements}Indirect[CountARB]`? Or do you absolutely have to have intermediate results in client memory?

Comment: @thokra very interesting thought. I'll have a look in that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both glMapBufferRange(..., GL_MAP_READ_BIT) and glGetBufferSubData() implicitly do something similar to glFinish(), which is not great for performance. You could avoid that by mapping your SSBO persistently and move your CPU processing to a different thread. The main GL thread and the CPU processing one will be synchronizing with glFenceSync() / glWaitSync() / glClientWaitSync().

Check out [this forum post](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/199140-Usage-of-GL_CLIENT_MAPPED_BUFFER_BARRIER_BIT?p=1285225#post1285225) discussing a similar problem.

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan: If you do it in one thread, you will end up blocking it in glClientWaitSync(). After thinking some more on this matter, it looks like not blocking the main GL thread is the only thing you can achieve using the technique I proposed. You won't be able to prevent draining the GL command queue, as there is no synchronization primitive in OpenGL that is signaled by the CPU and waited on by the GPU.